# can quartus synthesize a tri-state bus?

Tags: tri-state, quartus

1. Would the following Verilog be synthesize (in Altera's Quartus) to a bus of 1024 tri-state devices connected to one wire?
2. Will it be faster (clock latency) than a binary tree of 1024 or-gates?

`

```
module TriBus #(parameter N = 1024)(inb, enb, outb);

  input inb, enb;
  output outb;
  wire [N:1]inb;
  wire [N:1]enb;
  wire outb;
  wire [N:1] orbus;

  genvar I;
  generate
    for (I=1; I<N; I=I+1) begin
      assign outb = (enb[I])? inb[I] : 1'bz;
    end
  endgenerate
endmodule
```

`

Answer (score 1):

FPGA internals do not really do tristate, that is a feature of the IO drivers.

Ignoring issues of verilog syntax (I don't know the language) it might build, but is a bad idea, as I would expect it to be represented in reality by a stonking great mux, being the closest thing the internal fabric can get to a tristate bus, it is also possible that it may not build, as I say I don't know verilog.

You might want to take a careful look at the size of your parts LUTs before doing a binary tree, some of the more modern parts have 6 input LUTS that might make something else optimal.

I would also suggest that you are maybe thinking a little too close to the hardware, writing a mux something like (in VHDL) outb <= inb(selector); is likely to synthesise to something reasonably optimal and will not have possible 'X' or 'Z' states in its output.
My selector signal really wants to be a priority encoder over your enb lines unless you can do something more reasonable there, individual enables like this are a pain?

Regards, Dan.

Answer (score 0):

The primary distinction between a PLD and an FPGA is that a typical PLD element will have devices which AND together an arbitrary subset of a number of signals, while an FPGA will have every input of every internal device connected to exactly one output.  Use of three-state logic would be fundamentally incompatible with this model except in cases where exactly one device would be enabled at any given time.  In those cases, one could simulate the behavior of the three-state devices on the bus by having outputs that are always enabled but feeding them into a multiplexer.  Since such an implementation would generally be faster than an implementation using a tri-state bus (since switching bus ownership would typically require that bus release and bus acquisition occur as separate steps to ensure that the latter doesn't happen first), three-state buses would usually have little advantage outside of situations except in cases where they allow more efficient routing of signals that are not speed-critical.  Even in those cases, it may be possible to trade off some routing efficiency for speed (e.g. if one has 8 groups of 8 inputs scattered around the chip, running all 64 inputs to a single 8-bit mux would require running 64 wires to a common point.  Using three-state buses, one could have a 3-state buffer at each input controlled by one of 8 enable wires and feeding one of 8 data wires--only 16 wires total--or with more circuitry at each input one could cut that to 3 select wires and 8 data wires--11 total.  A big savings.  On the other hand, it's possible to achieve routing-space efficiency comparable to that of the tri-state-buffer approach if one uses seven sets of eight 2-way multiplexers instead of one set of eight 8-way multiplexers.  Consequently, while 3-state buses may sometimes have some advantages, they're seldom significant enough to justify the design effort required to use them.

Comment: "Since such an implementation would generally be faster than an implementation using a tri-state bus (since switching bus ownership would typically require that bus release and bus acquisition occur as separate steps to ensure that the latter doesn't happen first)" -- except, of course, in cases where the nature of the connected devices is such that there cannot be any contention because only one can be active at a time (e.g. the elements in a content-addressable memory).

Comment: @Jules: It's necessary to ensure that any device which releases a tri-state bus does so *definitely before* anyone else tries to acquire it.  If one device drives the bus whenever some signal "foo" is high, and some other device drives it whenever "foo" is low, and the first device happens to receive a rising edge slightly sooner than the second, that will create momentary bus contention.  The only way to avoid that is to force the first device to wait some time after the rising edge of "foo" before trying to drive the bus.

Answer (score 0):

Some FPGAs used to have internal tri-state drivers and routing (internal wiring). The Xilinx Spartan-II was one of these. I worked on a design that exploited this very ingeniously to produce a very dense circuit, so it was useful.

However, when multiple drivers can be enabled onto a single net, the FPGA draws more current, as it does when logic inputs are coming from undriven wires. The corruption of signals by competing drivers and the possibility of undriven wires all makes the timing more complicated to predict.

So internal tristates were abandoned in favour of all-unidirectional FPGA internal designs. As far as I've seen, all Altera and Xilinx devices in the last ten years or more have followed this path.